# display the values in a array using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How to use php foreach in the below case:

var_dump($dasboardStat);

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { 
        ["expenseType"]=> string(13) "Communication" 
        ["totalprice"]=> string(2) "99" 
    } 
    [ 1 ]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { 
        ["expenseType"]=> string(14) "Sales/Purchase" 
        ["totalprice"]=> string(4) "1900" 
    } 
    [ 2 ]=> object(stdClass)#6 (2) { 
        ["expenseType"]=> string(7) "Vehicle" 
        ["totalprice"]=> string(3) "210" 
    } 
    [3]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { 
        ["expenseType"]=> NULL 
        ["totalprice"]=> string(4) "2209" 
    } 
}
```

The array is the result of a mysql query, below is the sql query and the result screenshot. The expenseType will be more than 3 type , in below case only three types have entered into the database.

[the sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOcUk.png)

[the result array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHLTT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $object){
    foreach($object as $key){
        echo $key . " => " . $object->$key;
    }
}
// Will output:
// "expenseType => Communication
// totalprice => 99"
// and so on...
```

Comment: this works but at the end after the 2nd loop it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
foreach($dasboardStat as $row){
    $expenseType = $row->expenseType;
    $totalprice = $row->totalprice;

    // Do what you want ....
}
```